# Is regional accreditation important for a masters degree?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, united-states, accreditation

My understanding is that a regionally accredited school is important for getting into other schools, such as when applying for a masters program. But considering a masters program is typically the end of the road, is the type of accreditation important when looking at schools for a masters degree?

If choosing between two schools:

- A. Regionally accredited, but less desired degree
- B. Nationally
  accredited, but more desired degree

(desired = more desired degree type by the industry)

For example:

- A. Regionally accredited; MS in Game Design and Development
- B. Nationally accredited; MS in Computer Science with heavy emphasis on Game design and development

To gain entry into the game industry as a programmer, a computer science degree probably goes further than a game design and development degree. Both schools would provide the networking.

Do employers care about accreditation type?

Comment: Are you referring to programs in the US?

Comment: @ff524 yes. updated question

Comment: I'm not sure this question can be answered here, since it asks about what employers in industry think (not employers in Academia). This site has experts with knowledge of Academia, not necessarily industry employers. ([workplace.se] is the place to ask about expectations of employers in industry, but [similar questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3495/what-do-hr-departments-think-of-for-profit-universities-such-as-university-of-ph) have been closed as opinion based there, so I'm not sure how this would be received.)

Comment: @ff524 i tried to make this as unopinionated as possible while still providing all potentially relevant information.  Maybe I should remove the request of what would employers think.  I am just trying to find out if accreditation type matters in graduate school, or if it just matters in undergraduate school.  I don't know who else to ask.  Should I remove/rephrase the last line in my question?

Comment: "Do employers care about accreditation type?" - Does something give you the impression that they would? I would be surprised if they knew this difference even exists in the first place.

Comment: For those who didn't know the difference (such as yours truly) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_accreditation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field of game design and development is relatively new and specialized.  The best potential employers are quite likely to know the reputations of institutions that offer suitable degrees.  Therefore, I would say that the reputation of the institution is probably more important than either the exact degree title or the accrediting agency.

You probably have a small number of target employers in mind.  Try to find out where their employees went to school.